# How to disable multiple lines with a single command?

Tags: comments

I want to disable all the following lines:

```
\begin{flushright}
flush right\\
text
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushleft}
flush left\\
text
\end{flushleft}
```

I know that `%` at the beginning of a line will disable the the line. But I want to disable many lines using a command one time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
flush right\\
text
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushleft}
flush left\\
text
\end{flushleft}
\noindent MKs \hfill MKS
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to inactive more than one lines with a single command using only one time ?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean by that. Also (as has been comented many times) please don't put your question in the comments.

Comment: I have got my answer from '
    Commenting out large sections'. Thank you.